# Haskell: How to use forkIO to enable multiple clients to connect to a server?

Tags: networking, haskell

I'm trying to get multiple clients to connect to a server. What I've managed to do is connect one client to a server by using for the server:

```
main = withSocketsDo $ do 
          socket                 <- listenOn port
          (handle, host, portno) <- accept socket
          hSetBuffering handle LineBuffering
          msg <- hGetLine handle
          putStrLn $ "The client says: " ++ msg
          hClose handle
          sClose socket
          putStrLn "Server is done."
```

and for the client:

```
main = withSocketsDo $ do
  handle <- connectTo "localhost" port
  hSetBuffering handle LineBuffering
  hPutStrLn handle "Hello!"
  hClose handle
```

These are clearly just for testing purposes ;)

Now, I've read that I need to use forkIO to enable multiple clients to connect to this one server. However I haven't been able to find how I should use forkIO or how to manage the several clients that will connect. Can someone explain to me what I should do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as a general style comment, I'd split the reaction of the server to the client's connection into a separate function. This makes it easier to read in my opinion

```
main = withSocketsDo $ do
    socket <- listenOn port
    accept socket >>= handleClientRequest socket

handleClientRequest socket (handle, host, portno) = do
      hSetBuffering handle LineBuffering
      msg <- hGetLine handle
      putStrLn $ "The client says: " ++ msg
      hClose handle
      sClose socket
      putStrLn "Server is done."
```

now we probably want it to loop indefinitely, as that tends to be how most servers work. So we use forever (from Control.Monad)

```
main = withSocketsDo $ do
    socket <- listenOn port
    forever $ accept socket >>= handleClientRequest socket

handleClientRequest socket (handle, host, portno) = do
      hSetBuffering handle LineBuffering
      msg <- hGetLine handle
      putStrLn $ "The client says: " ++ msg
      hClose handle
      sClose socket
      putStrLn "Server is done."
```

and from here, the manner in which to use forkIO becomes quite clear

```
main = withSocketsDo $ do
    socket <- listenOn port
    forever $ accept socket >>= forkIO . (handleClientRequest socket)

handleClientRequest socket (handle, host, portno) = do
      hSetBuffering handle LineBuffering
      msg <- hGetLine handle
      putStrLn $ "The client says: " ++ msg
      hClose handle
      sClose socket
      putStrLn "Server is done."
```

Comment: Yes, I figured that I should split it into a separate function. Thanks for your clear and instructive answer!

Comment: You shouldn't `sClose` the listening socket in your request handler. The socket needs to stay open for the other `accept` calls.

Comment: Agreed; however I tried to avoid making changes to the original poster's code.

Answer (score 10):

The key is that once you've accepted a connection using `accept`, you'll want to fork a new thread to handle the connection while the main thread goes back to listening. So something like this should do the trick.

```
main = withSocketsDo $ do 
          socket <- listenOn port
          -- We want to accept multiple connections,
          -- so we need to accept in a loop
          forever $ do 
              (handle, host, portno) <- accept socket
              -- But once we've accepted, we want to go off and handle the
              -- connection in a separate thread
              forkIO $ do
                  hSetBuffering handle LineBuffering
                  msg <- hGetLine handle
                  putStrLn $ "The client says: " ++ msg
                  hClose handle
```

Note that this way the server keeps running until you kill the process, which is common behavior for many servers. Implementing more graceful shutdown will require some cross-thread communication using MVars or STM.

Comment: Note that `forkIO` is an `IO () -> IO ThreadId`, meaning, it returns the process ID of the child that is spawned, which can be used to kill your children. Not your real children. :P

Comment: Thanks, Hammar, this works fine! Oh and Dan, you cracked me up! ;)